# Numpy: Array Division with many 1's in Divisor

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to devise an efficient method to perform array division on NumPy where the divisor is largely made up of 1's.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(3,3)
B = np.array([[1,1,3],[1,1,1],[1,4,1]])

Result = A/B
```

Here, only 2 instances of the division operation are really required. I am not sure if Numpy is already optimized for division by 1 but my gut feeling is that it isn't.

Your ideas, please?

Comment: Checking for 1s and skipping the division is going to be way more expensive than just dividing, no matter how you do it. If you can track the position of the non-1 array elements, so you don't have to go through all the 1s to locate the non-1s, you might be able to shave some time off, but make sure you actually time it.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the division to selected items of `A` and `B`:

```
In [249]: A=np.arange(9.).reshape(3,3)

In [250]: B = np.array([[1,1,3],[1,1,1],[1,4,1]])

In [251]: I=np.nonzero(B>1)

In [252]: I
Out[252]: (array([0, 2], dtype=int32), array([2, 1], dtype=int32))

In [253]: A[I] /= B[I]

In [254]: A
Out[254]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.66666667],
       [ 3.        ,  4.        ,  5.        ],
       [ 6.        ,  1.75      ,  8.        ]])
```

Also a boolean index: `A[B>1] /= B[B>1]`

I doubt if it's faster.  But for other cases, such as a `B` that contains `0` it is a way of avoiding errors/warnings.  There must be a number of SO questions about `numpy division by zero`.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I didn't do a very thorough test, but filtering the division by searching for 1's in the denominator seems to slow things down, slightly, even when the fraction of 1's is very high (99%) (see code below). This suggests that the search for 1's `denom[np.where(denom<>1.0)]...` slows things down. Perhaps Numpy already optimizes array divisions in this way?

```
import numpy as np

def div(filter=False):
    np.random.seed(1234)
    num = np.random.rand(1024)
    denom = np.random.rand(1024)
    denom[np.where(denom>.01)] = 1.0
    if not filter:
        return num/denom
    else:
        idx = np.where(denom<>1.0)[0]
        num[idx]/=denom[idx]
        return num

In [17]: timeit div(True)
10000 loops, best of 3: 89.7 µs per loop

In [18]: timeit div(False)
10000 loops, best of 3: 69.2 µs per loop
```

Comment: I tried this with hpaulj's boolean indexing approach (`num[num<>1]/=denom[num<>1]`), and the same results obtain.